# Navigation components popupTo issue

Tags: kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

Navigation component popupTo(destination) not working, in between fragment stays in stack
here is my navigation

A->B->C->B->C...->B(button click)->D
A->B->C->B->C...->C(button click)->D

on clicking B or C , able to launch D but one one instance of B and C stays in stack.
Any idea what is happening ?

Comment: What do you mean by `but one one instance of B and C stays in stack`? I see a lot of B and C in the back stack. Which ones do you want to keep and which ones to remove?

Comment: B and C are recursive. I am poping everytime after navigate to B or C. but one instance of both stays in Backstack. eventhough i added PopupInclusive = "true"

Comment: Say you have A->B->C, now you navigate from C->B, what backstack do you want here?

Comment: C->B->D. Till D its going but on pressing back it gets B then C then A. I want to go to A from D

Comment: You can set the actions B->D and C->D to popUpto A (inclusive = false). If that doesn't work, add your nav graph in the question.

Comment: popUpToInclusive and popUpTo  in navigation graph solved my issue.  Thanks @ArpitShukla for your help. Appreciate